# Move the counter under and to the right of the progress bar Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm using Bootstrap 3 for my site, and I need some help with the progress bar.
I'd like to move the counter under the progress bar and also another example to move the counter to the right of the progress bar.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/83Qhw/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="50" style="width: 0%;">
    <span class="sr-only">100%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.progress {
    background: linear-gradient(#D6D9DB, #E4E7E9) repeat scroll 0 0 #D6D9DB;
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF, 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    }

.progress .progress-bar {
    background: #75b1d9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #75b1d9 0%,#3f81ad 50%,#3f81ad 51%,#1f72aa 52%,#1e73ac 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #75b1d9 0%,#3f81ad 50%,#3f81ad 51%,#1f72aa 52%,#1e73ac 100%);
    border: 1px solid #257fbd;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #176396 inset;
    line-height: 18px;
    }
```

Thank you in advance,
Cris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will give you an idea of how to accomplish this- but you will likely want to clean the code a little.

## [Underneath](http://jsfiddle.net/F9JpP/)

HTML

```
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="50" style="width: 0%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id='counter'></span>
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.progress .progress-bar').each(function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var perc = me.attr("aria-valuemax");
        var current_perc = 0;
        var progress = setInterval(function() {
            if (current_perc>=perc) {
                clearInterval(progress);
            } else {
                current_perc +=1;
                me.css('width', (current_perc)+'%');
            }
            $('#counter').text((current_perc)+'%');
        }, 50);
    });
},100);
```

CSS

```
.progress {
    background: linear-gradient(#D6D9DB, #E4E7E9) repeat scroll 0 0 #D6D9DB;
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF, 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    }

.progress .progress-bar {
    background: #75b1d9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #75b1d9 0%,#3f81ad 50%,#3f81ad 51%,#1f72aa 52%,#1e73ac 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #75b1d9 0%,#3f81ad 50%,#3f81ad 51%,#1f72aa 52%,#1e73ac 100%);
    border: 1px solid #257fbd;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #176396 inset;
    line-height: 18px;
    height:15px;
    }
```

## [Right](http://jsfiddle.net/Ykd5A/)

Note. Same JS and HTML as above.

CSS

```
.progress {
    background: linear-gradient(#D6D9DB, #E4E7E9) repeat scroll 0 0 #D6D9DB;
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF, 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    }

.progress .progress-bar {
    background: #75b1d9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #75b1d9 0%,#3f81ad 50%,#3f81ad 51%,#1f72aa 52%,#1e73ac 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #75b1d9 0%,#3f81ad 50%,#3f81ad 51%,#1f72aa 52%,#1e73ac 100%);
    border: 1px solid #257fbd;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #176396 inset;
    line-height: 18px;
    height:15px;
    }
#counter{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you!! :) so easy and I missed it!!